# How to use a NSStatusItem as a drag destination?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsdragginginfo

I'm trying to build an application that allows users to drag files from Finder to the menubar icon for processing.  I've made progress in my journey, but I can't seem to summit this hill.  I tried subclassing NSView and implementing the drag messages.

```
@interface CMDroppableView : NSView <NSMenuDelegate>
```

I wanted to not only accept drag operations, but to provide a NSMenu when the user clicks the icon.  I've managed to get the NSMenu to display properly, but the drag functionality remains elusive.

It's my understanding that I needed to register the accepted drag types which I have done here:

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{
[self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
}
```

Drag messages:

```
-(NSDragOperation)draggingEntered:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    NSLog(@"Drag Enter");
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

-(NSDragOperation)draggingUpdated:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return NSDragOperationCopy;
}

-(void)draggingExited:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    NSLog(@"Drag Exit");
}

-(BOOL)prepareForDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
     return YES;
}

-(BOOL)performDragOperation:(id <NSDraggingInfo>)sender{
    return YES;
}
```

Here is the code where the custom view is set:

```
statusItemView = [[CMDroppableView alloc] init];
[statusItemView retain];
[statusItemView setMenu: statusMenu];

[statusItem setView: statusItemView];
```

Still nothing.  So where have I gone wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you implemented the draggingEntered: and performDragOperation: methods?

Comment: Yes, I have.  I'll update my question to include them.

Comment: I suspect that you just won't be able to do this. Dragging an object to a menu is not a normal UI behaviour, and I think that there are probably system-level restrictions on the interactions that an `NSStatusItem` views can have. I'd be surprised if the view responded to anything other than a mouseUp/Down.

Comment: @Rob, that's interesting.  How then, do applications like CloudApp enable you to drop files on the statusbar icon?

Comment: You can do it just fine; I do it in a few apps of my own.

Comment: @Wevah, would you be kind enough to answer the question?

Comment: I can't see anything that he's done wrong, providing that he's using his custom view for the status item's view. :/

Comment: @Wevah, I updated my post to include the code where the custom view is set.  Would it be acceptable post all of the code to a pastiebin and link to it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: D'oh, you're registering the drag types in `-awakeFromNib`, which won't be called if the view isn't being loaded from a nib. Try registering your drag types in `-initWithFrame:` instead!

#### Old answer:

IIRC you need to not set the menu on the status item. What I do is have my custom view manage a menu, and do something like this:

```
- (void)setMenu:(NSMenu *)menu {
    [menu setDelegate:self];
    [super setMenu:menu];
}

- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)event {
    [statusItem popUpStatusItemMenu:[self menu]]; // or another method that returns a menu
}

- (void)menuWillOpen:(NSMenu *)menu {
    highlight = YES;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)menuDidClose:(NSMenu *)menu {
    highlight = NO;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect {
    NSImage *img = highlight ? [alternateImage copy] : [image copy];
    NSRect bounds = [self bounds];
    [statusItem drawStatusBarBackgroundInRect:bounds withHighlight:highlight];
    
    // rest of drawing code goes here, including drawing img where appropriate
}
```

in my custom view's implementation. This ensures the menu behavior is identical to the default.

Comment: I am setting the NSMenu to my custom view, not the NSStatusItem.  More importantly, how do you handle your drag destinations?

Comment: Oh, oops. I'll update my answer. Running low on sleep at the moment, though…

Answer (score 7):

Through trial and error I stumbled onto the solution.  I was registering my acceptable drag types within the awakeFromNib message (as seen in the original question).  However, I was not using IB to set this view up so this method was never called.  Moving the registration code to the initFromFrame message seemed to fix the problem.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        ...
        [self registerForDraggedTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType]];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I didn't read this self-answer before I edited mine. You should accept yours as the right one! (Voted up.)